# IFTTT - record timestamp (rather than time range) in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, ifttt

I created an IFTTT recipe that logs the time I arrive and leave work every day, but it always records it in 1hr blocks.

I'm using iPhone's location to track when I arrive and leave. Everything seems to be working, but calendar events are showing as 1hr blocks rather than just a timestamp.

For example, if I arrive at 8:05am it will show as a block on my calendar from 8:05 to 9:05 rather than just showing for one minute. I'd rather it just say "I arrived at work at 8:05". Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I right in assuming you used the default *"Track your work hours in Google Calendar"* applet made by *Google* ?

[image]

It uses the **Quick add event** action to add this event to your calendar.  Instead, create your own version of the applet that uses the **Create a detailed event** action.  This allows you to set the following parameters (specifically, it includes **Start time** and **End time**):

[image]

You can set the *start time* and *end time* to the same value, but it will, of course, still read as an event that runs from e.g. 9:05 to 9:05.

If you want to record just a single timestamp, you will need to use a different service to store your data.  Perhaps record the data in a *Google* spreadsheet ?

Any queries, post a comment and I'll get back to you.